# Theoretical question regarding differential equation leading to limit 0

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am new to differential equations, and am stuck at the following question:

Let $a$ and $b$ be real numbers. Given is the system:

$x'=ax+ay$

$y'=ax-(a+2b)y$

Which condition is identical to stating that each solution $\begin{pmatrix}x(t)\\y(t)\end{pmatrix}$ to the system satisfies $\lim_{t\to \infty}x(t)=\lim_{t\to \infty}y(t)=0$?

a. $a^2+b^2>0$

b. $a,b>0$

c. $-b<a<0$

d. $a>0>b$

Thank you!

Comment: Why don't you solve the diff. eq.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a simple test for the signs of the eigenvalues of a symmetric matrix. In the $2\times 2$ case both eigenvalues are negative if the upper left entry is negative and the determinant is positive.

For the present case $$A=\begin{pmatrix} a&a\\a&-a-2b\end{pmatrix}$$ this gives the conditions $$a<0~~\text{ and }~~-2a^2-2ab=-2a(a+b)>0.$$ The second inequality can be reduced to $a+b>0$. This is case c.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to write the differential eq. as
$\binom{x'(t)}{y'(t)} = A\binom{x(t)}{y(t)}$, where $A$ is the 2x2-matrix $A=\begin{pmatrix} a&a\\a&-a-2b\end{pmatrix}$. Try to find the eigenvalues of $A$ and understand under what conditions the matrix exponential of $A\cdot t$ converges to the zero-matrix when $t \to \infty$.

Comment: I double-checked, and this is the equation they gave (unless they made a mistake). I had already tried your methodology, actually, but the problem is that I get stick at the eigenvalue, because it got so complicated that I did not think I could calculate the eigenvectors for that. Are you saying I don't actually need the eigenvector?

Comment: The solution to the diff. eq. is $e^{At}x_0$, where $x_0$ is the initial condition. Since $e^{At}=Me^{Dt}M^{-1}$, you can write $e^{Dt}y_0 = M^{-1}x(t)$, where $D$ is the diagonal matrix of $A$ and $y_0$ is some other initial condition. Now $x(t) \to 0$ iff $M^{-1}x(t) \to 0$. As the eigenvalues only enter in $M$, I dont think you need to compute them.

Comment: Thank you Caroline!